# Swapping pixels in an icon with javascript?

Tags: javascript, pixel

I have a menu made up of icons and labels. When an icon is clicked the relevant label turns blue. I've recently heard about a technique called swapping pixels, and I wondered if it was possible to make the icon turn blue also? 
Pure Javascript if possible!

This is the code that I have at the moment...

```
function init() {

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navico'), function(el) { 
        el.addEventListener('click', imageButtonClickHandler); 
    });


    function imageButtonClickHandler() {  

    this.id.search("aboutnav"); 
       if(this.id.match("aboutnav")) {
            grey();
            var a = document.getElementById("a");
            a.style.color = 'blue';
            a.style.fontSize = '15px';

        }
```

the function 'grey' that gets called in the function above is JQuery and was created by my partner so I don't understand it, but it basically turns the selected menu option back to grey after it is deselected or a different icon is clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the icon is an image, there isn't a way to use JavaScript to modify the image directly.  There are, however, techniques for modifying how images look by using other images.

For example, if "turning the icon blue" meant that you wanted to change a specific pattern of colors in the icon you could create another image with just the parts you want to turn blue and everything else in the image transparent (think cut-out).  Then, position the image at the same location as your icon with a higher z-index but set its visibility:hidden (or display:none, if you'd rather).  Then turning the image blue would just mean showing the image.

If turning the icon blue meant that you wanted it to just have a blue "tinge" to it, you could create a semi-transparent png and use the same technique.  You could also accomplish a blue tinge by just creating an element (say a div) and setting the background color to blue, then setting the transparency.  In this way you could choose arbitrary colors instead of having to create an image for each color you wanted to use.